# How to prevent function count when link clicking in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, meteor, counting

I use Meteor and there is MongoDB as the database.
I try to list the item number myself by "count" variable.
But every time I click on the link on Navbar, it count without resetting.

For example first time the result of clicking "Contacts" on Navbar show below.

```
---------------------------------
Contacts   Products   Solutions
---------------------------------
item   user
1      a
2      b
3      c
```

When I click "Contacts" again, it shows as below.

```
---------------------------------
Contacts   Products   Solutions
---------------------------------
item   user
4      a
5      b
6      c
```

How can I prevent the javascript to run this every time I click Link?

In my code as below, I have the problem with "countRegister" variable:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table, Alert, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Registers } from '../../api/registers';


let countRegister = 0


const DSRegisters = ({ registers, match, history }) => (
            <div className="Registers">
                <div className="page-header clearfix">
                    <h4 className="pull-left">Registration</h4>
                    <Link className="btn btn-success pull-right" to={`${match.url}/new`}>Add User</Link>
                </div>
                {registers.length ? <Table striped responsive>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Salution</th>
                        <th>Firt Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Province</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th />
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {registers.map(({ _id, regsId, salution, firstname, lastname, province, country, status, username }) => (
                    <tr key={_id}>
                        <td>{countRegister += 1}</td>
                        <td>{salution}</td>
                        <td>{firstname}</td>
                        <td>{lastname}</td>
                        <td>{province}</td>
                        <td>{country}</td>
                        <td>{status}</td>
                        <td>{username}</td>
                        <td>
                            <Button
                                bsStyle="primary"
                                onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}/${_id}`)}
                                block
                            >View</Button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Button
                                bsStyle="danger"
                                onClick={() => handleRemove(_id)}
                                block
                                >Delete</Button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table> : <Alert bsStyle="warning">Nobody yet!</Alert>}
            </div>
);

DSRegisters.propTypes = {
  registers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('registers');
  return {
    registers: Registers.find({}, { sort: { regsId: 1 } }).fetch(),
  };
}, DSRegisters);
```

Comment: Don't you just want to show `_id` instead of the global var `countRegister`?

Comment: I want to show the list number 1,2,3,...... but _id is not the list number.

Comment: use `register.map(({ _id, regsId, salution, firstname, lastname, province, country, status, username }, index) => <tr key={_id}><td>{index}...</td>`

Comment: @alphiii That would count starting from 0 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to show 1, 2, 3 each time you render the component, you shouldn't use the global var `countRegister`. The problem here is that as long as you don't refresh the website, your `countRegister` variable will never reset to 0, as it is a global variable that gets initialized only once, and so the count will continue to increase.

Instead, you could use the second argument of the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, nl, the index

```
registers.map(({ 
  _id, 
  regsId, 
  salution, 
  firstname, 
  lastname, 
  province, 
  country, 
  status, 
  username 
}, index) => ( // <- index is the second argument, starting from 0
  <tr key={_id}>
    <td>{( index + 1)}</td> // <- so to show 1, 2, 3, increase it by 1
    <td>{salution}</td>
    // ...
```

This will keep your count the way you want it